# 18.04: 'system program problem detected' error prevents installing apps

Tags: 18.04

On a HP Probook 430 G1, I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04, and I constantly see a pop-up stating *system program problem detected*  right after I boot. There is an option to report it which I did. In /var/crash there are two crash reports:

_opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000

_usr_bin_gnome-shell.121.crash

At the same time, what I'm really experiencing is that I can't install some programs neither from Ubuntu Software neither via downloading them. For example, I fail to install ClamTK and Double Commander which I had previously. However, I was able to install Skype.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Read the `/var/crash` files with `less`. Click on "Show Details" in the pop- up. Only ask 1 question at a time.

Comment: I failed to read the files. In the terminal window it says 'No such file or directory'.
The pop-up doesn't have an option 'Show details'. Just 'Cancel' and 'Report'.
My bad, I just thought those two issues were interelated.